# Create complex membership area with mean stack : Which technology?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm looking for the right technology to build my project, and I'm thinking about using the mean stack.
But I wonder if they is some CMS, starter kits or other things that should help me.

I would like to create a "complex" membership area, where my customers will be able to :
- connect
- see their products and trainings (I offer trainings with the products)
- Buy products they havn't bought yet

And for my admin pannel :
- Membership management
- Ad products to the membership area
a few other functionnalities

So do you know  if their is an existing technology I could use to develop it faster ?

Thank you !

Comment: There are 'some CMS, starter kits or other things'. Browse Github for them, depending on your needs and technologies you're after. Asking for libraries and other off-site resources is prohibited on SO.

Comment: Oh is it ? Didn't know that

Comment: Cause I know that there are CMS and other things, I found a lot, but none really seems to fit my needs, and I need some advices about that

Comment: Yes, this sort of questions is off-topic for several years. Try Quora or Reddit. And the answer will really depend on what your needs are.